# What is the best way to dump entire objects to a log in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, object, logging

So for viewing a current object's state at runtime, I really like what the Visual Studio Immediate window gives me.  Just doing a simple

```
? objectname
```

Will give me a nicely formatted 'dump' of the object.

**Is there an easy way to do this in code, so I can do something similar when logging?**

Comment: In the end, I've used T.Dump quite a bit.  It's a pretty solid solution -- you just need to be careful of recursion.

Comment: This is an old question, but comes out at the top of a lot of search hits. For future readers: See [this vs extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29872430/906773). Worked great for me in VS2015.

Comment: Update for 2020 since that VS plugin isn't maintained and lacks some features. The following library does the same thing in code - and it has a few extra features, e.g. it tracks where it's already visited to avoid loops: https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper

Answer (score 102):

For a larger object graph, I second the use of Json but with a slightly different strategy. First I have a static class that is easy to call and with a static method that wraps the Json conversion (note: could make this an extension method).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class F
{
    public static string Dump(object obj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```

Then in your `Immediate Window`,

```
var lookHere = F.Dump(myobj);
```

lookHere will auto-show up in the `Locals` window prepended with a $ or you can add a watch to it. On the right hand side of the `Value` column in the inspector, there is a magnifying glass with a dropdown caret beside it. Choose the dropdown caret and choose Json visualizer.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2013 Locals window]

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: SerializeObj -> SerializeObject?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I cannot install debug tools for Visual Studio on my remote server, and this thing works extremely well in my asp.net mvc app.

Comment: For nice formatting you can do: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleData, Formatting.Indented)`

Comment: so much easier than trying to do it by hand. It gets complicated

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5+, you can also use out of the box API `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(yourObject)`.

Comment: This solution works nicely as an extension method. Simply modify to `public static string Dump(this object obj)`.

Answer (score 44):

You could use Visual Studio Immediate Window

Just paste this (change `actual` to your object name obviously):

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actual);
```

It should print object in JSON
[image]

You should be able to copy it [over textmechanic text tool](http://textmechanic.com/Find-and-Replace-Text.html) or [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) and replace escaped quotes (`\"`) with `"` and newlines (`\r\n`) with empty space, then remove double quotes (`"`) from beginning and end and paste it to [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to make it more readable.

**UPDATE to OP's comment**

```
public static class Dumper
{
    public static void Dump(this object obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)); // your logger
    }
}
```

this should allow you to dump any object.

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Thanks.  Perhaps you didn't catch it in my original question, but I indicated that I already knew about the immediate window, and I wanted to do the same thing when logging in my app.

Comment: @DanEsparza `Console.Log(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actual));` ? :) and yes I indeed missed it. This question comes up when you search https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=100&safe=off&espv=2&q=c%23+object+to+json+immediate+window&oq=c%23+object+to+json+immediate+wind&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i21.3714.5236.0.6083.9.8.1.0.0.0.302.860.0j2j1j1.4.0.ckpsrh...0...1.1.64.serp..7.2.492.S1GYb6M5xFw

Comment: FYI, when you have a JSON string in a C# string, click on the spyglass icon to the right of the string and pick the Text Visualizer. It will bring up a window that shows a plain text version of the JSON string (not escaped quotes or \r\n).

Answer (score 29):

I'm certain there are better ways of doing this, but I have in the past used a method something like the following to serialize an object into a string that I can log:

```
  private string ObjectToXml(object output)
  {
     string objectAsXmlString;

     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(output.GetType());
     using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
     {
        try
        {
           xs.Serialize(sw, output);
           objectAsXmlString = sw.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           objectAsXmlString = ex.ToString();
        }
     }

     return objectAsXmlString;
  }
```

You'll see that the method might also return the exception rather than the serialized object, so you'll want to ensure that the objects you want to log are serializable.

Comment: In the light of the features added to C# after you answered the question might be useful to point out that this implementation works nicely as an extension method. If applied to Object class and you reference the extension everywhere you need it, it could be a convenient way to call the function.

Comment: I keep getting from this: ``Failed to access type 'System.__ComObject' failed``. Noob to c#, would appreciate help.

Comment: @GuySoft I suspect one of the properties on your object, or the object itself, is not serializable.

Comment: You can't use this method on classes without a parameterless constructor, unfortunately. They are not serializable.

Answer (score 22):

[ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) has a [T.Dump() extension method](https://docs.servicestack.net/dump-utils) that does exactly this, recursively dumps all properties of any type in a nice readable format.

Example usage:

```
var model = new TestModel();
Console.WriteLine(model.Dump());
```

and output:

```
{
    Int: 1,
    String: One,
    DateTime: 2010-04-11,
    Guid: c050437f6fcd46be9b2d0806a0860b3e,
    EmptyIntList: [],
    IntList:
    [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    StringList:
    [
        one,
        two,
        three
    ],
    StringIntMap:
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for fields. The OP was explicitly asking about "entire objects".

Comment: `He didn't say fields` - he said `entire objects`, which includes fields. He also mentioned Visual Studio's Immediate Window feature as an example what of he wanted to achieve (*"Just doing a simple `? objectname` will give me a nicely formatted 'dump' of the object"*). `? objectname` prints out all the fields as well. `This has been immensely helpful - one of my most used extension methods to date` - I'm not questioning that it's useful, only that it dumps entire objects.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Wrong **entire objects** means a recursive dump of the object, NOT that it includes fields, which can easily lead to infinite recursive loop. You shouldn't assume what others are implying. My answer is both relevant and helpful, your down vote + comment is not.

Comment: @mythz yes of course you need to prevent a stack overflow (eg. every `Int32` field has a `MaxValue` field, which is an `Int32` itself...), that's a good point, but it doesn't change the fact that objects - and certainly entire ones - consist of fields, too, not just properties. What's more (you did not address that one), `? objectname` in the `Immediate Window` **does** display fields - without triggering an infinite loop. If that's about my downvote, I can withdraw it (if you let me by unlocking it, that is). I disagree in principle anyway.

Comment: @mythz, by the way, there is a possibility of an infinite loop in case of properties as well, isn't it? If your class is `public class Nested { public Nested Child { get; set; } }`, you can do `var root = new Nested(); root.Child = root;` Unless I am misunderstanding you somehow on that one.

Comment: @KonradMorawski You can prevent stackoverflows by maintaining state, which is something most and fast serializers don't do. You have a better chance of controlling the external shape of your type via public properties than is done with internal fields which are freely added without care.

Comment: Still relevant and helpful 11 years later. But apparently `ServiceStack.Text` was not free for some period.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a stupidly simple way to write a flat object, nicely formatted:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

Debug.WriteLine("The object is " + JObject.FromObject(theObjectToDump).ToString());
```

What's going on is that the object is first converted to a JSON internal representation by `JObject.FromObject`, and then converted to JSON string by `ToString`.  (And of course a JSON string is a very nice representation of a simple object, especially since `ToString` will include newlines and indents.)  The "ToString" is of course extraneous (as it's implied by using `+` to concat a string and an object), but I kinda like to specify it here.

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apprec,Formatting.Indented) for comfortable reading in log

Answer (score 5):

You could use reflection and loop through all the object properties, then get their values and save them to the log.  The formatting is really trivial (you could use \t to indent an objects properties and its values):

```
MyObject
    Property1 = value
    Property2 = value2
    OtherObject
       OtherProperty = value ...
```

Answer (score 5):

What I like doing is overriding ToString() so that I get more useful output beyond the type name.  This is handy in the debugger, you can see the information you want about an object without needing to expand it.

Answer (score 5):

Following is another version that does the same thing (and handle nested properties), which I think is simpler (no dependencies on external libraries and can be modified easily to do things other than logging):

```cs
public class ObjectDumper
{
    public static string Dump(object obj)
    {
        return new ObjectDumper().DumpObject(obj);
    }

    StringBuilder _dumpBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    string DumpObject(object obj)
    {
        DumpObject(obj, 0);
        return _dumpBuilder.ToString();
    }

    void DumpObject(object obj, int nestingLevel = 0)
    {
        var nestingSpaces = "".PadLeft(nestingLevel * 4);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}null\n", nestingSpaces);
        }
        else if (obj is string || obj.GetType().IsPrimitive)
        {
            _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}\n", nestingSpaces, obj);
        }
        else if (ImplementsDictionary(obj.GetType()))
        {
            using (var e = ((dynamic)obj).GetEnumerator())
            {
                var enumerator = (IEnumerator)e;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    dynamic p = enumerator.Current;

                    var key = p.Key;
                    var value = p.Value;
                    _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} ({2})\n", nestingSpaces, key, value != null ? value.GetType().ToString() : "<null>");
                    DumpObject(value, nestingLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (obj is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (dynamic p in obj as IEnumerable)
            {
                DumpObject(p, nestingLevel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);

                _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} ({2})\n", nestingSpaces, name, value != null ? value.GetType().ToString() : "<null>");
                DumpObject(value, nestingLevel + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    bool ImplementsDictionary(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.Name.Contains("IDictionary"));
    }
}
```

Comment: this will die horribly if you have a `Date` property in your inner object ... just saying ...

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'. Using for a CharArea object

Answer (score 5):

Today you don't even need an external dependency. You can just use the built-in [Microsoft Json Serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace MyCompany.Core.Extensions
{
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static string Dump(this object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you can pass a [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0) parameter to further customize the serialization to your liking:

[image]

Let's say you want to write the JSON indented for easy reading... we'd use:

```
   new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }
```

#######

Here's a good guide if you wish to migrate from `NewtonSoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`:

[Compare Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json, and migrate to System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: Today? What version of .net

Comment: @deltanine Net-6

Answer (score 4):

I found a library called [ObjectPrinter](https://github.com/drewburlingame/ObjectPrinter) which allows to easily dump objects and collections to strings (and more). It does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new library, consumed via NuGet, called [Dumpify](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dumpify).

It has `Dump()` extension methods to Dump objects into Console, Debug, Trace or any TextWriter you provide.
It supports Properties, fields and private members and is highly configurable.

Examples:

```
var moaid = new Person { FirstName = "Moaid", LastName = "Hathot" };
var haneeni = new Person { FirstName = "Haneeni", LastName = "Shibli" };

moaid.Spouse = haneeni;
haneeni.Spouse = moaid;

moaid.Dump();
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own WriteLine method-

```
public static void WriteLine<T>(T obj)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        var props = t.GetProperties();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in props)
        {
            sb.Append($"{item.Name}:{item.GetValue(obj,null)}; ");
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Use it like-

```
WriteLine(myObject);
```

To write a collection we can use-

```
 var ifaces = t.GetInterfaces();
        if (ifaces.Any(o => o.Name.StartsWith("ICollection")))
        {

            dynamic lst = t.GetMethod("GetEnumerator").Invoke(obj, null);
            while (lst.MoveNext())
            {
                WriteLine(lst.Current);
            }
        }
```

The method may look like-

```
 public static void WriteLine<T>(T obj)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        var ifaces = t.GetInterfaces();
        if (ifaces.Any(o => o.Name.StartsWith("ICollection")))
        {

            dynamic lst = t.GetMethod("GetEnumerator").Invoke(obj, null);
            while (lst.MoveNext())
            {
                WriteLine(lst.Current);
            }
        }            
        else if (t.GetProperties().Any())
        {
            var props = t.GetProperties();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in props)
            {
                sb.Append($"{item.Name}:{item.GetValue(obj, null)}; ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Using `if, else if` and checking interfaces, attributes, base type, etc. and recursion (as this is a recursive method) in this way we may achieve an object dumper, but it is tedious for sure. Using the object dumper from Microsoft's LINQ Sample would save your time.

Comment: Out of curiousity: How does this handle arrays or lists?  Or properties that reference parent objects?

Comment: @DanEsparza Thanks to show me the way to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

All of the paths above assume that your objects are serializable to XML or JSON,
or you must implement your own solution.

But in the end you still get to the point where you have to solve problems like

- recursion in objects
- non-serializable objects
- exceptions
- ...

Plus log you want more information:

- when the event happened
- callstack
- which threead
- what was in the web session
- which ip address
- url
- ...

There is the best solution that solves all of this and much more.
**Use this Nuget package: [Desharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Desharp/).**
For all types of applications - both **web and desktop applications**.
See it's **[Desharp Github documentation](https://github.com/debug-sharp/desharp)**. It has **many configuration options**.

Just call anywhere:

```
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyException);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyCustomValueObject);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyNonserializableObject);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyFunc);
Desharp.Debug.Log(anyFunc, Desharp.Level.EMERGENCY); // you can store into different files
```

- it can save the log in nice HTML (or in TEXT format, configurable)
- it's possible to write optionally in background thread (configurable)
- it has options for max objects depth and max strings length (configurable)
- it uses loops for iteratable objects and backward reflection for everything else,
  indeed for **anything you can find in .NET environment**.

I believe it will help.

Answer (score 3):

So far a simplest and tidiest way for me is a serializer from `YamlDotNet` package.

```
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

List<string> strings=new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
new Serializer().Serialize(strings)
```

will give you

```
- a
- b
- c
```

A more comprehensive example is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/KuV63n

Comment: I have to admit:  I like how clean this looks

Comment: Wow YAML, perfect solution <3

Answer (score 2):

Based on @engineforce answer, I made this class that I'm using in a PCL project of a Xamarin Solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42264037/6155481
/// </summary>
public class ObjectDumper
{
    public static string Dump(object obj)
    {
        return new ObjectDumper().DumpObject(obj);
    }

    StringBuilder _dumpBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    string DumpObject(object obj)
    {
        DumpObject(obj, 0);
        return _dumpBuilder.ToString();
    }

    void DumpObject(object obj, int nestingLevel)
    {
        var nestingSpaces = "".PadLeft(nestingLevel * 4);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}null\n", nestingSpaces);
        }
        else if (obj is string || obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive || obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
        {
            _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1}\n", nestingSpaces, obj);
        }
        else if (ImplementsDictionary(obj.GetType()))
        {
            using (var e = ((dynamic)obj).GetEnumerator())
            {
                var enumerator = (IEnumerator)e;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    dynamic p = enumerator.Current;

                    var key = p.Key;
                    var value = p.Value;
                    _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} ({2})\n", nestingSpaces, key, value != null ? value.GetType().ToString() : "<null>");
                    DumpObject(value, nestingLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (obj is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (dynamic p in obj as IEnumerable)
            {
                DumpObject(p, nestingLevel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo descriptor in obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object value = descriptor.GetValue(obj);

                _dumpBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} ({2})\n", nestingSpaces, name, value != null ? value.GetType().ToString() : "<null>");

                // TODO: Prevent recursion due to circular reference
                if (name == "Self" && HasBaseType(obj.GetType(), "NSObject"))
                {
                    // In ObjC I need to break the recursion when I find the Self property
                    // otherwise it will be an infinite recursion
                    Console.WriteLine($"Found Self! {obj.GetType()}");
                }
                else
                {
                    DumpObject(value, nestingLevel + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bool HasBaseType(Type type, string baseTypeName)
    {
        if (type == null) return false;

        string typeName = type.Name;

        if (baseTypeName == typeName) return true;

        return HasBaseType(type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType, baseTypeName);
    }

    bool ImplementsDictionary(Type t)
    {
        return t is IDictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: useless for complex objects. fails with stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: [CSharpObjectFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Scripting/CSharp/Hosting/ObjectFormatter/CSharpObjectFormatter.cs) from the  [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/).

[C# REPL Command-Line Interface (CSI.EXE)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting) and [CSharpRepl](https://github.com/waf/CSharpRepl) use exactly this formatter.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.Hosting;

var students = new[]
{
    new Student
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Michael Hilus"
    },
    new Student
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Alicia Keys"
    }
};

var formattedStudents = CSharpObjectFormatter.Instance.FormatObject(students);

Console.WriteLine(formattedStudents);
```

Output:

```
Student[2] { Student { Id=1, Name="Michael Hilus" }, Student { Id=2, Name="Alicia Keys" } }
```

But it's suitable for relatively simple objects, for example it can't dump the instance of [System.Data.DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0).

**Option 2**: [vm.Aspects.Diagnostics.ObjectTextDumper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/vm.Aspects.Diagnostics.ObjectTextDumper) - [see documentation](https://github.com/vmelamed/vm/blob/master/Aspects/Diagnostics/ObjectTextDumper/README.md).

There is also very popular library:
[ObjectDumper.NET](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper), it's an open source, but not free for commercial use.