# Recursive log object properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, recursion

I would like to log to file every WCF parameters. I use parameter inspector and create recursive code for inspecting every property in every class in all inputs (my code is similar to: [How to recursively print the values of an object's properties using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196413/how-to-recursively-print-the-values-of-an-objects-properties-using-reflection)) so I can log in file like:

```
MethodName(string="aaa", ComplexClass=[prop="aaa", prop2="bbb"])
```

Unfortunately I have to change my code to do not log properties which are marked with custom attribute called NoLog. I modified my code to get attributes of every property but because every time I'm inspect parameters my code really slow down.

So my question is: how can I provide caching?

Comment: Your logging requirements are so special that the built-in [wcf logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) is no good?

Comment: Are you able to reach, and/or install, an AppFabric Caching server?

Comment: @rene this attribute for example means that wcf logging is wrong in this case

Comment: @Michael AppFabric has no use here

Comment: @Garath, I guess you already have a solution in mind then huh?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud AppFabric it is a way where I can store the cache, but I want to know how to create fast code for caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public B BValue { get; set; }

    public A()
    {
        this.Id = 1000;
        this.BValue = new B();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public C CValue { get; set; }
    [NoLog]
    public string Secret { get; set; }

    public B()
    {
        this.Name = "Empty Name";
        this.CValue = new C();
    }
}

public class C
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public C()
    {
        this.Description = "Empty Description";           
    }
}
```

and NoLog custom attribue:

```
public class NoLogAttribute : Attribute
{

}
```

According to your question you use sth like this to pretty print:

```
public static void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent = 4, char intendCharacter = ' ')
    {
        if (obj == null) return;
        string indentString = new string(intendCharacter, indent);
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var pName in GetPropertiesToLogWithCaching(obj))
        {
            var property = objType.GetProperty(pName);
            object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);
                PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
            }
        }            
    }
```

I changed the way how we access properties (by name) and added for this two methods:

```
public static List<string> GetPropertiesToLogWithCaching(object obj)
    {
        List<string> propertiesToLog = new List<string>();
        if (obj != null)
        {
            string key = obj.GetType().FullName;
            propertiesToLog = CacheLayer.Get<List<string>>(key);
            if (propertiesToLog == null)
            {
                propertiesToLog = GetPropertiesToLog(obj);
                CacheLayer.Add<List<string>>(propertiesToLog, key);
            }
        }
        return propertiesToLog;
    }

    public static List<string> GetPropertiesToLog(object obj)
    {
        List<string> propertiesToLog = new List<string>();
        if (obj != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => !Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(NoLogAttribute))))
            {                   
                propertiesToLog.Add(p.Name);
            }
        }
        return propertiesToLog;
    }
```

where GetPropertiesToLogWithCaching is wrapper of GetPropertiesToLog. ChacheLayer object you can find here http://www.deanhume.com/home/blogpost/object-caching----net-4/37

Now it is recursive and it has caching. As I wrote in first version of answer. The idea is to chache list of properties names and than GetProperty by name without testing attributes as a key for cache we can use FullName of obj Type. Now you need to check how it works.

Comment: I changed this a bit, but it is ok