# C# and use of reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, iteration

I came over this site (http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=17637), which illustrates use of reflection like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

   private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new Person { Age = 30, Name = "Tony Montana" };
        var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(person, null));
        }
    }
```

The codesnippet above will give you:
Age: 30
Name: Tony Montana

What if we added "Kid" to the class "AnotherPerson" like this

```
    public class Kid
    {
        public int KidAge { get; set; }
        public string KidName { get; set; }
    }
    public class AnotherPerson
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Kid Kid { get; set; }
    }
```

This snippet;

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var anotherPerson = new AnotherPerson { Age = 30, Name = "Tony Montana", Kid = new Kid { KidAge = 10, KidName = "SomeName" } };
        var properties = typeof(AnotherPerson).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(anotherPerson, null));
        }
    }
```

gives me: 
Age: 30
Name: Tony Montana
Kid: ProjectName.Form1+Kid

Not quite what I was looking for.... Could I use reflection to iterate trough "Kid" also? Suggestions?

Comment: Do the same for `kid` object

Comment: Are you actually interested in some form of serialization, like JSON? http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: you will need to recursively call your outputting method and look to see if a property is an object i believe this question does it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196413/how-to-recursively-print-the-values-of-an-objects-properties-using-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Could have a helper method which is something like this?

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetPropertiesRecursive(object instance)
{
  List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> propValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
  foreach(PropertyInfo prop in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    propValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(instance, null));
    propValues.AddRange(GetPropertiesRecursive(prop.GetValue(instance));
  }
}
```

Call as - `GetPropertiesRecursive(anotherPerson)`

Comment: You don't need `Type` parameter

Comment: @I4V was just about to change that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var anotherPerson = new AnotherPerson { Age = 30, Name = "Tony Montana", Kid = new Kid { KidAge = 10, KidName = "SomeName" } };
    var properties = typeof(AnotherPerson).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Kid)){
            var pp = typeof(Kid).GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine("Kid:");
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in pp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0} = {1}", p.Name, p.GetValue(anotherPerson.Kid, null));
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(anotherPerson, null));
    }
```

Comment: What would happen if the OP added an `Adolescent` type to the `AnotherPerson`? The idea of reflection in this context is probably to make it as generic as possible for the future :)

Comment: This is far too inflexible.

Comment: True, for it to be _flexible_ you should treat primitive types, arrays, lists, dictionaries and indexed properties.

Comment: Not even that, it's too tightly coupled to the classes themselves. A good *flexible* solution would check whether the property itself is a class or whether it's a value type & deal with it in that way.

Comment: @James But it's not just whether the type is a value type or not; it's a question of whether the type overrides `ToString` in a way that provides as much information as you want.  There are plenty of custom value types that won't do this, and plenty of custom classes that will.

Comment: @Servy well given the question (and example) the OP provided I doubt they are looking to take it to that level. The question was geared towards outputting basic value type properties, not gauging whether the type itself has a custom implementation of `ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

The code loops through the properties and uses `ToString` (through the `String.Format` method that `Console.WriteLine` uses) to get the string representation of the property values.

If you want to change how the `Kid` property value is displayed, you basically have two options:

1. Check the type of the property (`property.PropertyType`) in the reflection code, so that you can do something different for the `Kid` type.
2. Override the `ToString` method in the `Kid` class, so that it returns whatever string you want to display as value.

Answer (score 0):

A method doing some recursion can get the values for properties within properties:

```
public static string GetProperties(object obj)
{
    var t = obj.GetType();
    var properties = t.GetProperties();
    var s = "";
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, new object[0]);
        string propertyToString;
        if (t.GetMethod("ToString").DeclaringType != typeof(object))
            propertyToString = propValue.ToString();
        else if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            propertyToString = Convert.ToString(propValue);
        else
            propertyToString = GetProperties(propValue);

        s += string.Format("'{0}' = '{1}'", property.Name, propertyToString);
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you had practical purposes in mind, JSON (or other) serialization may be more appropriate, e.g. using [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) would produce a similar string.