# How to print the information out of a KeyValuePair<K,T> in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, keyvaluepair

I have a list of `KeyValuePair<K,T>`. I would like to print the details from `T`, but I do not know its type in order to do a cast. For example the value stored in `T` could be a `Student`, a `Person`, a `Movie`, etc, and I would like to print out the information. Assuming I have `p as KeyValuePair`, I tried doing `p.Value.ToString()` but it would only print out the type. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *override* `ToString` method in your types if you wanna get meaningful outputs when you call it.

You can find detailed explanation in here about how to do it:

- [How To: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Why did I not think of that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to print property values: [How to recursively print the values of an object's properties using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196413/how-to-recursively-print-the-values-of-an-objects-properties-using-reflection)

```
public void PrintProperties(object obj)
{
    PrintProperties(obj, 0);
}
public void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{
    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);
            PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use reflection: [C# getting its own class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113069/c-sharp-getting-its-own-class-name)

`this.GetType().Name`

Selman22's solution is if you want to really control the output of what gets printed - usually a better strategy if you can control the ToString on all the objects.

Comment: Selman22's solution is easier and is better for my needs. I'm trying to understand yours as well. Thank you!