# in unity how to i print a serializable class to the console?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to see the object structure as a string that can be printed to the console but cannot seem to achieve this. Im using the following code:

```
Debug.Log(character.Serialize());
```

where character is the serializable class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no immediate way.
You have some solutions, either you override the ToString and do this for every class you want to print:

```
public override string ToString(){
    return string.Format("{0}:{1}",pippo,pluto);
}
```

where pippo and pluto either are primitive that can be printed or a complex Class with an overridden ToString().

Or you make a Json out of it, like the following: 
http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2014/01/29/dumping-objects-one-property-at-a-time-with-console-writeline-a-pretty-printer-for-c-objects-thats-good-enough/

or

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5

But it would require an external library.

It's probably the same question posted here, though: [C#: Printing all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852181/c-printing-all-properties-of-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use json.net unity plugin and call:

```
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject);
```

works like a charm.