# Print linq query (select *l)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, printing

i need to print all rows from one table.
avoid placing: s.Adress+s.EmployeeID, etc

```
var query = from x
            in bd.Employees
            where x.City == "London" && x.TitleOfCourtesy == "Mr."
            select x;

foreach(var s in query)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s.Address+"---"+s.EmployeeID);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message??

Comment: What is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So whats the problem? Describe it more precisely please.

Comment: I want to print all rows from each column from table Employees (Northwind db), without writing each of the columns names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: Printing all properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852181/c-printing-all-properties-of-an-object)

Comment: not much, i'm still trying

Comment: I suggest you update the question to make it a bit clearer what it is you want. As a possible solution to the problem you are trying to solve, have you looked into using reflection?

Comment: Is it working now @oms ?

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` takes params so you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}---{1}", s.Address, s.EmployeeID.ToString());
```

Or you can use C# 6.0 string interpolation (Note the dollar sign):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{s.Address}---{s.EmployeeID}");
```

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned in the comments:

> I want to print all rows from each column from table Employees (Northwind db), without writing each of the columns names

You can do this, imagine you have a class:

```
public class One
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can:

```
// using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var one = ser.Serialize(new One() { Id = 1, Name = "George" });

Console.WriteLine(one);
```

Comment: @mjwills The OP added that in the comments after I answered the question. Nonetheless, I edited the answer. Thanks for the heads up.