# how can I print an object using Windows Forms in C#

Tags: c#

I was getting an error about trying to push null into the field, which was a Foreign key in the table I was using. So I changed it, but I am not sure if I grabbed the right object, so I want to print what I just pushed the database table. I am aware that I can query the table, but given that I only see the id, and it is almost midnight, I feel better if I can just print it and make sure it is the value I just created in the form. Here is the code...

```
foreach (TeamModel tm in model.EnteredTeams)
{
     var p = new DynamicParameters();
     p.Add("@TournamentId", model.Id);
     //p.Add("@PrizeId", tm.Id);
     //p.Add("@PrizeId", model.Prizes);
     p.Add("@PrizeId", model.Prizes.First().Id);
     p.Add("@Id", 0, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
     connection.Execute("spTournamentPrizes_Insert", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     MessageBox.Show("This is the prize you just pushed to the Database." , model.Prizes.First());

 }
```

As you can see I am trying to use MessageBox, but it is only for strings apparently according to the documentation I read. How can I print what is the Prize object?

Comment: Hope [ObjectDumper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852216/3796048) is gonna help you.

Comment: What you probably should do is read [ask] to start with.

Comment: You have to do : `MessageBox.Show("This is the prize you just pushed to the Database." , model.Prizes.First().Id.ToString())`

Comment: A good class has (at least) a ToString function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what i would do:

Write a method to convert Prize object to string inside Prize class like:

```
public string GetPrizeDetailsAsString()
{
return "ID:"+Id.ToString()+..... // u can add all the params from prize which u wanna view;
}
```

then calling model.Prize.First().GetPrizeDetailAsString() will give you the complete details.

eg:

```
 MessageBox.Show("This is the prize you just pushed to the Database." , model.Prizes.First().GetPrizeDetailAsString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write method to return the values from the Prize object.

```
public string ConvertPrizeToString(Prize prize)
{
    return string.Format("Id:{0}, Other Details:{1}", prize.Id, prize.OtherDetails);
}
```

Then you can call the function in MessageBox

```
MessageBox.Show("This is the prize you just pushed to the Database.", ConvertPrizeToString(model.Prizes.First()));
```