# Print out 1 object in a List of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a List containing several objects.
Is there any way I can print out just one of the objects?

`Console.WriteLine(myList.ElementAt(1));`

This line of code does not give me the object. It does however give me the name of the Class.

Comment: You need to print out the object properties one by one. Like `Console.WriteLine(myList.ElementAt(1).Name);` for example. Or override the `ToString` method, but that's usually not the right solution.

Comment: You have to override the .ToString(). For your object.
Then you can say myList.ElementAt(1).ToString()

Comment: By default, [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) returns a fully-qualified name of the type. If you need to display something different (some of the properties e.g. name) you need to override it. If you need a generic method to print all of the object properties to console, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852181/c-printing-all-properties-of-an-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways.

1. Access the properties separately

   ```
   var element = myList.ElementAt(1);
   Console.WriteLine("ID:{0}, Name:{1}", element.ID, element.Name);
   ```

---

2. or overload the `ToString()` for the class

   ```
   public class myObject
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return string.Format("ID:{0}, Name:{1}", ID, Name);
       }
   }
   ```

   so you can

   ```
   Console.WriteLine(myList.ElementAt(1));
   ```

Comment: @JohnCarlson if this answer solved the problem, you should accept it as an answer to let other users know.

Comment: @Frauke I tried to, but it wouldn't let me at the time. Just came back to my computer. Answer is accepted! :)