# C# Outputting own Data Types of List

Tags: c#

I´m new to C# and have the following problem: If I try to Console out all of my Parts from the part List it´s always giving me: "Parts" as the output. I want it to give out all of my propertys like:
1. Partname = "TestEntry",PartID=1234 . Am I missing something?. And my second question is: Whats the best way to store Datas from a Database to represent them in my application. Should i store them also in Lists? Thanks to everyone!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
    parts.Add(new Part() {PartName="TestEntry", PartId=1234});
    parts.Add(new Part() {PartName="TestEntry2", PartId=12354});

    parts.ForEach(entry => Console.Write("{0}\n", entry));
  }
}


class Part{
  public string PartName { get; set; }
  public int PartId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360277/what-is-the-best-way-to-dump-entire-objects-to-a-log-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852181/c-printing-all-properties-of-an-object

Comment: Override the [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method, or create a method called `GetOutputFormat` that returns the string you want to output and print that

Comment: > Whats the best way to store Datas from a Database to represent them in my application. Should i store them also in Lists?

--

Depends what you use to read from DB, you can use `HashSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by specifying which properties of the `entry` to output in your foreach loop:

```
parts.ForEach(entry => Console.Write($"Partname = \"{entry.PartName}\", PartID={entry.PartId}\n", entry));
```

You can also keep your loop as is, and instead override the `ToString` method of your `Part` class:

```
class Part
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Partname = \"{PartName}\", PartID={PartId}";
    }
}
```

All objects have a [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring) method defined. The default implementation is to return a string which represents the fully qualified name of the type for the object. When you simply do `Console.Write(myObject);`, then the `ToString` method is called, in order to return a string that represents the object. If you want to customize what is returned from calling `ToString`, you need to override the method inside the class.

Comment: Thank you. I don´t understand why overriding the ToString() Method affects my Console.Write() Method. Can you explain me this?

Comment: @WomEpic Sure, I've updated the answer with an explanation. Hope this helps :)