# VS2005 Debugger: Adding a watch on specific fields within all objects of a list?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, debugging

Visual Studio 2005 allows you to add a watch on particular elements of a list.  For example, let's say we have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
  string name;
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

And then we declare:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
```

... and it fills up with thousands of elements.  I know that it is possible to add a watch on the expressions foos[1].x or foos[i].x.  What I would like to know is whether I can add a watch on foos[all].x so that my watch window will automatically look like this:

```
foos[0].x = 1
foos[1].x = 2
// ...
foos[foos.Count-1].x = 42
```

This would save a great deal of time in allowing me to visualize the contents of my list.  Does VS2005 or one of its plugins have a way to accomplish this?  How about VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 'watch' window, inside of that you can add any watch variable that you want. Also check that [article](http://saraford.net/2008/02/12/did-you-know-you-can-use-the-watch-window-to-quickly-change-a-variables-value-149/) that i quickly found in google.

For dynamic watch you can use [Debug.Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksxtc1s6.aspx):

for example :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < foos.Count(); i++)
 {
    Debug.Print("foos[{0}].x={1}",i,foos[i].x);
 }
```

Comment: I know about the watch window.  My question was asking whether you can programmatically add a watch for foos[i].x, for all i, without knowing how many items are in the list.

Answer (score 2):

how about "object dumper" ?

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/25/all-about-objectdumper.aspx

or

[C# object dumper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347375/c-object-dumper)