# JSON formatting using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, formatting, indentation, javascriptserializer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set formatting with JavaScriptSerializer when JSON serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881204/how-to-set-formatting-with-javascriptserializer-when-json-serializing)

I'm using using System.Web.Script.Serialization to serialize some json. However, by default it makes ugly text without indentation.

```
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,dynamic>>(s);

    // do something else to the json...

    //serialize the result
    string serialized = serializer.Serialize(json);
    // ugly text
```

I'm looking at the second overload and it takes a StringBuilder. I've not used these much. Can I use that to format pretty JSON? How would I do that in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imho, it's not possible to the JavaScriptSerializer how to format the ouput-string (in contradiction to XmlWriter for XmlSerializer)...

in my use-cases i ever decided to go with [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/), it's more powerfull, a lot of faster and for JSON ;)

Comment: Does it support dynamic typed objects during deserialization? I hate having to make structs or type definitions to match my json, or lists.

Comment: I suppose it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net