# Xamarin: string represantation of object

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for something similar in `Xamarin` to `iOS` `-description` method which is just string representation of object (called when u type `po` object in `XCode` console)

F.e I'm getting a `Array` or `Dictionary` and I need to display it in a `label`

in `iOS` I'd easilly do:

```
label.text = object.description;
```

and it would work for `dictionary` and `arrays`:

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7f8a83ef4b10>(
{
    description = "set_loyalty";
    event = "";
    mutation = 100;
    previous = 0;
    timestamp = "2016-04-08 09:45:15";
},
{
    description = "set_loyalty";
    event = "";
    mutation = 100;
    previous = 100;
    timestamp = "2016-04-08 09:45:16";
},
```

but in Xamarin I weren't able to find easy way to achieve the same.

I've tried:

- object.toString();
- String.Format("{0}", object);
- object.Description;

None of it works like I want (I don't expect it to work :) like I want )

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an iOS object (inherits from `NSObject`), you can still use `myObect.Description`.

If not:

- some types overload `ToString()` to print their properties nicely, but not all
- have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1347630/1489968
- or use a serializer of your choice (e.g. [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)). But these will not dump every field / property.

Comment: I love already xamarin, it crashes when I'm using:
labelResponse.Text = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (data);

Exception: Specified cast is not valid

Comment: what's the inner exception? What type has your `data` ?

Comment: I have currently Foundations object like NSDictionary and NSArray

Comment: As I said. If it's `NSObject` (`NSDictionary` is) you can use `.Description`. What happened, when you tried `.Description`? You say, it's not working for you.

Comment: but .Description returns just first symbol like {
 but I have data {{     points = 0; }} Foundation.NSDictionary

Comment: I think its because of the newlines. Set `label.Lines = 0` and give it enough height.

Comment: I can easy check it assigning to string

Comment: yes, was lines = 0... Omg, so for Foundation object I can use .Description, for other I'd use JSON.Net, thanks