# deserialize json into list of anonymous type

Tags: asp.net, json, anonymous-types, servicestack

I have a json as below :

```
  "[{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"a":"e","c":"f"},{"a":"g","c":"h"}]"
```

now I want to deserilize this into a list of objects of anonymous type "foo"

```
  var foo=new { a=string.empty , c=string.empty };
```

the code is :

```
  ServiceStackJsonSerializer Jserializer = new ServiceStackJsonSerializer();
  dynamic foos = Jserializer.Deserialize<List<foo.GetType()>>(jsonString);
```

but not working .

update :

replacing `ServiceStack` with `JavascriptSerializer` and passing `dictionary[]` solved the problem without need to `anonymous` Type

```
        JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var Foos = jSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>[]>(jsonString);
```

Comment: See my answer to see how this can be done with ServiceStack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870906/deserialize-json-into-list-of-anonymous-type/11877087#11877087

Comment: This has exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026040/8644294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the `Jserializer` class is, but I do know of the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class.  Unfortunately, it doesn't support deserialization into anonymous types.  You'll have to create a concrete type like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public string a { get; set; }

    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code worked for me:

```
const string json =
    @"[{""a"":""b"",""c"":""d""},{""a"":""e"",""c"":""f""},{""a"":""g"",""c"":""h""}]";

var foos = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Foo[]>(json);
```

the variable `foos` will contain an array of `Foo` instances.

Comment: thank you , but I am looking for a way to avoid creating concrete type if possible .

Comment: as json content was made of <string,string> pairs , I used dictionary<string,string>[] as Type and it worked

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can [dynamically parse JSON with ServiceStack's JsonSerializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/GitHubRestTests.cs) e.g:

```
var json = "[{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"},{\"a\":\"e\",\"c\":\"f\"},{\"a\":\"g\",\"c\":\"h\"}]";

var dictionary = json.FromJson<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
".NET Collections:".Print();
dictionary.PrintDump();

List<JsonObject> map = JsonArrayObjects.Parse(json);
"Dynamically with JsonObject:".Print();
map.PrintDump();
```

Which uses [ServiceStack's T.Dump() extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360277/what-is-the-best-way-to-dump-entire-objects-to-a-log-in-c/3514115#3514115) to print out:

```
.NET Collections:
[
    {
        a: b,
        c: d
    },
    {
        a: e,
        c: f
    },
    {
        a: g,
        c: h
    }
]
Dynamically with JsonObject:
[
    {
        a: b,
        c: d
    },
    {
        a: e,
        c: f
    },
    {
        a: g,
        c: h
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you . but now, I don't know which serializer to choose . which one has a better performance ?

Comment: ServiceStack by far :) http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/#burningmonk-benchmarks

Answer (score 1):

For what you are trying to do it sounds like json.net would be a better fit.  See this question
[Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: thank you , but that works if json contains just one item , but here it contains more than one . I need to extract a list or array of anonymous objects

Answer (score 0):

The below example can deserialize JSON to a **list** of anonymous objects using [NewtonSoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)'s [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) method.

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TestJSONFiles\yourJSONFile.json");
var fooDefinition = new { a = "", b = 0 }; // type with fields of string, int
var fooListDefinition = Enumerable.Range(0, 0).Select(e => fooDefinition).ToList();

var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, fooListDefinition);
```