# Deserializing JSON response without creating a class

Tags: c#, json

From the result of an API call I have a large amount of JSON to process.

I currently have this

```
Object convertObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
```

I am aware that I could do something like

```
Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(responseFromServer);
```

And then use it like

```
m.FieldName
m.AnotherField
//etc
```

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
var itemName = convertObj["Name"];
```

to get the first Name value for the first item in the list.

Is this possible, or do I have to create a class to deserialize to?

The reason I do not want to create the class is I am not the owner of the API and the field structure may change.

Edit.

Okay so I created the class as it seems the best approach, but is there a way to deserialize the JSON into a list?

```
var sessionScans = new List<SessionScan>();
sessionScans = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionScan>(responseFromServer);
```

Complains that it cannot convert SessionScan to generic list.

Comment: u can use `Dynamic` but it is not recommended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava why is it *not recommended* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

Comment: @Jim bcoz dynamic typing is that it often hides bugs that would be otherwise revealed during compilation. Such bug then only manifests on run-time, which of course makes it much harder to detect.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava yes I agree completely with you. On the other side, the question essentially is *Deserializing JSON response without creating a class*.

Answer (score 20):

No need to use `dynamic`, you can simply use `JToken` which is already does what you expect:

```
var json = @"
    {
        ""someObj"": 5
    }
";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
var t = result["someObj"]; //contains 5
```

Answer (score 12):

With **.NET 6**, this can be done as below,

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

string jsonString = @"some json string here";

JsonNode forecastNode = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)!;

int temperatureInt = (int)forecastNode!["Temperature"]!;
Console.WriteLine($"Value={temperatureInt}");

//for nested elements, you can access as below
int someVal = someNode!["someParent"]["childId"]!.ToString();
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0) MS docs page for more samples - create object  using `initializers`, make `changes` to DOM, deserialize `subsection` of a JSON payload.

Comment: Check out the new [improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-8/) in `.NET 8` for `System.Text.Json`, it is much better now.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with `JObject.Parse` :

```
dynamic convertObj = JObject.Parse("{ 'Name': 'Jon Smith', 'Address': { 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY' }, 'Age': 42 }");

string name = convertObj.Name;
string address = convertObj.Address.City;
```

Answer (score 2):

The below example can deserialize JSON to a **list** of anonymous objects using [NewtonSoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)'s [DeserializeAnonymousType](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) method.

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TestJSONFiles\yourJSONFile.json");
var fooDefinition = new { FieldName = "", AnotherField = 0 }; // type with fields of string, int
var fooListDefinition = new []{ fooDefinition }.ToList();

var foos = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, fooListDefinition);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem working with unknown APIs then I decide to come over this problem using this approach, I'm writing down here my test case:

```
            [TestMethod]
        public void JsonDocumentDeserialize()
        {
            string jsonResult = @"{
""status"": ""INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"",
    ""timestamp"": ""09-09-2019 11:00:24"",
    ""message"": ""documentUri is required.""
}";

            var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonResult);
            if (jDoc.RootElement.TryGetProperty("message", out JsonElement message))
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(message.GetString() == "documentUri is required.");
            }
        }
```

it worked for me because first I was looking to find a way to use dynamic type as it's mentioned in Azure Function HTTPTrigger. But I found this approach most useful and robust.

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-5-0#use-jsondocument)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET's LINQ to JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
string prop = (string)o["prop"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json = "[{'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc'},{'a':'aa','b':'bb','c':'cc'}]";
var ja = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var jo = (JObject) ja[0];
Console.WriteLine(jo["a"]);
```