# Iterating over dictionary obtained through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

So I have this code which is supposed to recursively print all the properties and their content of a given object.

```
static public void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{
    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly && !property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);
            PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (null != propValue)
            {
                Type t = propValue.GetType();
                //Console.WriteLine(":::::{0}:::::", propValue.GetType());
                bool isDict = t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>);
                if (isDict)
                {
                    Type keyType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    Type valueType = t.GetGenericArguments()[1];
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<keyType, valueType> kvp in (Dictionary<keyType, valueType>)propValue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work for `List` and `Dictionary` yet, I'm working on the `Dictionary` part right now.

Problem is, I extract the type of the key and value with:

```
Type keyType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type valueType = t.GetGenericArguments()[1];
```

But then VS2013 tells me that there is a problem with this line:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<keyType, valueType> kvp in (Dictionary<keyType, valueType>)propValue)
```

It tells me that the type or namespace KeyType and valueType are not found.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

PS : .net 4.5.1

Comment: `keyType` & `valueType` in your example are instances of `Type` but `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` requires a type name so that the type can be evaluated at runtime.  You'll have to access the dictionary using the non-generic `Dictionary` class and cast the key & value objects manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to dump entire objects to a log in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360277/what-is-the-best-way-to-dump-entire-objects-to-a-log-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Basically your `keyType` & `valueType` are variables of type `Type`, which are known at runtime, so you'd have to use reflection to cast your `propValue` to an appropriate generic Dictionary. You can however use the fact that, for backwards compatibility, `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements the non generic `IDictionary` interface.

So in your specific case, it would be enough to replace this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<keyType, valueType> kvp in (Dictionary<keyType, valueType>)propValue)
```

with this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in (IDictionary)propValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

In calls to generic methods you must provide actual type names (or pass generic type parameters from your own method's definition) - not instances of `Type`.

Comment: So there is no way to automatically print the content of a dictionnary extracted through reflection? because in `propValue` I can see the type of both the key and value (example : `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary 2[Mobile.Fonct
ionComptage.Modele.IndexFournisseur, System.String]`)

Answer (score 1):

As decPL indicated, you should use System.Collections.IDictionary.  However you should also change your isDict logic.  System.Type.IsAssignableFrom allows you to check if "an instance of a specified type can be assigned to the current type instance".  Here is code showing it's behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing System.Type.IsAssignableFrom");

            var propValue = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "hello", "world" } };
            var t = propValue.GetType();
            bool isDict = typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t);
            if (isDict)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in (IDictionary)propValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So your method should look like this.

```
static public void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{
    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly && !property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);
            PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (null != propValue)
            {
                Type t = propValue.GetType();
                //Console.WriteLine(":::::{0}:::::", propValue.GetType());
                bool isDict = typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t);
                if (isDict)
                {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in (IDictionary)propValue)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

However you could also do this with the C# as operator.  The as operator will attempt to do a cast to the specified type.  If it is not possible, it returns null.  Some sample code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing System.Type.IsAssignableFrom");

            var propValue = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "hello", "world" } };
            IDictionary asDict = propValue as IDictionary;
            if (asDict != null)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in (IDictionary)propValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And your method.

```
static public void PrintProperties(object obj, int indent)
{
    if (obj == null) return;
    string indentString = new string(' ', indent);
    Type objType = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = objType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object propValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == objType.Assembly && !property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}:", indentString, property.Name);
            PrintProperties(propValue, indent + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (null != propValue)
            {
                var asDict = propValue as IDictionary;
                if (asDict != null)
                {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in asDict)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}: {2}", indentString, property.Name, propValue);
        }
    }
}
```