# What is the proper way to display a List of different types in c#?

Tags: c#

Ok, so basically I am creating a project that requires to Create, Read, Update, and Delete. However, I am not referring to a database server, but a List of type. I am trying to figure out how to display the list of Dvd type. My first goal is to be able to display the list of DVDs before starting to implement the update and delete method. Here are my classes:

DvdController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DvdManager.Models;
using DvdManager.Data;

namespace DvdManager.Controllers
{
    public class DvdController
    {
        List<Dvd> Dvds = new List<Dvd>(10);       


        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Dvd Manager");

            CreateDvd();
        }

        private void CreateDvd()//Create
        {
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(0, "Batman", 2010, "Bruce", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(1, "Superman", 2009, "John", 4));
            Dvds.Add(new Dvd(2, "Wonderwoman", 2012, "Omar", 4));
            DisplayDvds();
        }

        private void DisplayDvds() //Read List<Dvd> dvds
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Dvds.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Dvds[i]);
            }
        }

        private void SearchDvds() //List
        {

        }

        private void EditDvd(int id, Dvd dvd) //Update
        {

        }

        private void RemoveDvd(int id) //Delete
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Dvd.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;    

namespace DvdManager.Models
{
    public class Dvd
    {
        public Dvd(int id, string title, int releaseyear, string director, float rating)
        {
            Id = id;
            Title = title;
            ReleaseYear = releaseyear;
            Director = director;
            Rating = rating;
        }

        int Id { get; }
        string Title { get; set; }
        int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        string Director { get; set; }
        float Rating { get; set; }


    }
}
```

The problem is that it displays:

> DvdManager.Models.Dvd

But, what I want it to do is display its value by Id, Title, ReleaseYear, Director, Rating. How do I succeed in doing this?

Comment: You could override ToString() in Dvd class

Comment: Your question mentions a list of different types, but your code shows only one type, the `Dvd` type. There are many ways to show the values of properties of an object in the console; see [What is the best way to dump entire objects to a log in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/360277/215552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the default string representation of your class as returned by its `ToString`. If you want a different output, you can override `ToString` yourself. E.g.:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return string.Format
              ("DVD [Id: {0}; Title: {1}; ReleaseYear: {2}; Director: {3}; Rating: {4}]",
               Id, Title, ReleaseYear, Director, Rating);
}
```

Comment: Or , with string interpolation `public override string ToString() => $"DVD [Id: {Id}; Title: {Title}; Release year: {ReleaseYear}; Director: {Director}; Rating: {Rating}]";`

Comment: Very important question, is there a way to access id, title, releaseyear, director, or rating by index in the DvdController.cs? For example, if I wanted to remove by id, this would not work: Dvds.Remove(Dvds.Single(x => x.Id == 2));

Comment: Actually I was supposed declare the properties as public, that is why it was not working due to protection level.